# Implementation of a derived interface

Tags: c++, diamond-problem

In my code I had an interface and its implementation:

```
class Interface
{
public:
    virtual ~Interface() {}
    virtual void f() = 0;


};
class Impl : public Interface
{
public:
    virtual ~Impl() {}
    virtual void f() {
        // ...
    }
};
```

However one beautiful day I decided that I need to enrich my interface with a new method, so I created a derived interface:

```
class InterfaceExt : public Interface
{
public:
    virtual ~InterfaceExt() {}
    virtual void g() = 0;
};
```

Now I need an implementation of the new interface, but I would like to reuse the existing implementation of the old interface, so I tried to do something like this:

```
class ImplExt : public virtual InterfaceExt, public virtual Impl
{
public:
    virtual ~ImplExt() {}
    virtual void g() {
        // ...
    }
};
```

It seems reasonable, compiler should see that all methods from InterfaceExt are accessible in ImplExt. Unfortunately, it doesn't compile:

`diamond.cpp:38: error: cannot declare variable 'a' to be of abstract type 'ImplExt'
diamond.cpp:25: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'ImplExt':
diamond.cpp:5: note:    virtual void Interface::f()`

Of course, I can always to something like

```
virtual void f() {
    Impl::f();
}
```

but in my real code I have a lot of methods, and doing this kind of thing would be quite tedious. I was hoping that there is a better solution.

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Have you modify InterfaceExt  to `class InterfaceExt : public virtual Interface` ?

Comment: You may be running into this problem: https://crazycpp.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/name-resolution-and-overloading/

Comment: Your approach is good, also correctly realized that this is a `diamond-problem`, the only issue is that you used `virtual inheritance` at the wrong place. `InterfaceExt` and `Impl` should derive virtually.

Comment: Putting virutal to the right place solved the issue, thanks!